# Redmine & Subversion Edge on the same Win Box

Tags: apache-2.2, svn, redmine, multiple-instances, subversion-edge

We will be installing both Subversion Edge and Redmine, but have the requirement that they run on the same box.

The easiest way to install Redmine would appear to be using a BitNami Stack.

Our Inf Struct team only has IIS experience so I'll be helping them, but I'm unsure on the easiest way to get it up and running since both require Apache, but both have they're own pre-setup configurations that most likely are not compatible.

How should I suggest we go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did exactly this setup today in a vmware (Windows Server 2003) and i only had to change the default port of the apache server running in the bitnami stack to be different from the CollabNet apache port. You can do this on one of the bitnami stack install screens.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. We'll be installing this in the next few hours so I'll give it ago.